# Relacionamento muitos para muitos com Asp.net MVC e Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Estou criando um projeto para estudar `Asp.net MVC 5` junto com `Entity Framework 6`, e me deparei com uma grande dúvida em um **relacionamento de muitos para muitos**. Utilizei model gerado a partir da base de dados, e criei os *controllers* e *views* automáticamente pelo *Visual Studio*.

Em minha base de dados tenho o relacionamento de muitos para muitos entre a tabela **Usuário** e **Projetos**, o que resulta na tabela **Equipe_Projeto** como segue a imagem abaixo:

[image: DER da aplicação]

Essa tabela, como o próprio nome diz, está desenhada para armazenar os dados dos usuários que farão parte de algum projeto, ou de vários.

Ao criar o meu **edmx** em meu projeto do *Visual Studio*, a tabela **Equipe_Projeto**, não é criada nas classes models, e somente o relacionamento vai no *edmx*, como na imagem abaixo:

[image: Diagrama edmx da aplicação]

Logo, me deparo com a questão de como vou popular a minha tabela de **Equipe_Projeto**? Estou um pouco perdido aqui em como vou relacionar os meus usuários com os projetos, utilizando asp.net MVC?

No código do método Create do projeto tenho o código a seguir, e neste não há nada que relacione a tabela **Equipe_Projeto**:

```
// GET: Projeto/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.prioridade = new SelectList(db.prioridade, "prioridade1", "prioridade1");
    ViewBag.status = new SelectList(db.status, "status1", "status1");
    ViewBag.responsavel = new SelectList(db.usuario, "id", "nome");
    return View();
}

// POST: Projeto/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id,nome,descricao,data_inicio,responsavel,prioridade,status")] projeto projeto)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.projeto.Add(projeto);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.prioridade = new SelectList(db.prioridade, "prioridade1", "prioridade1", projeto.prioridade);
    ViewBag.status = new SelectList(db.status, "status1", "status1", projeto.status);
    ViewBag.responsavel = new SelectList(db.usuario, "id", "nome", projeto.responsavel);
    return View(projeto);
}
```

A grande dúvida é esta, como trabalhar com o relacionamento muitos para muitos, de forma que eu consiga inserir dados em mais de uma tabela ao mesmo tempo, no meu caso na tabela **Projeto**, e **Equipe_projeto**, definindo assim os usuários que fazem parte do projeto.

Obs: Eu tenho uma grande experiência já com projetos em WebForms, porém agora estou indo atras do aprendizado em asp.net mvc, entity framework e webapi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A criação das tabelas por EDMX faz o Entity Framework configurar essa tabela associativa pela `Fluent API`, dentro do seu arquivo de contexto (uma classe que deriva `DbContext`). Por experiência própria, não recomendo usar desta forma por três motivos:

- Não é claro como e em que momento o Entity Framework fará a associação pra você;
- A associação não pode ser estendida, receber mais propriedades, regras, etc.
- O seu exemplo já mostra que não existe *Scaffolding* (prototipação automática) da associação, e ela tem que ser feita manualmente.

O ideal seria você criar o *Model* `Equipe_Projeto` manualmente, associando `Projeto` e `Equipe` como 1 para N. Isto evita a confusão.

Além disso, não recomendo você continuar muito tempo nesta abordagem com o arquivo EDMX. Com o uso de `Attributes`, essa abordagem se torna rapidamente obsoleta.

Comment: Valeu @CiganoMorrisonMendez, obrigado. Seguindo o seu conselho, vou criar o model manualmente e fazer a associação. Feito isso, eu altero o controller do Projeto para que ele também deva "enxergar" esta associação, assim inserindo na base de dados também os usuários que fazem parte do projeto. E qual maneira você me recomendaria na questão do uso de Attributes do edmx?

Comment: @EricoSouza Usar Attributes em EDMX fica bem complicado. Eu faria toda a declaração de *Models* textualmente, por classe. Pode até não ser intuitivo no começo, mas o ganho que se tem com validação e regras de negócio com esse tipo de disciplina vale todo o esforço.

Comment: @CiganoMorrizonMendez, atualmente venho utilizando classes de metadados, nela tenho os Attributes, e validação e regras nela e não no EDMX. Você acredita que seja válido essa abordagem?

Comment: @EricoSouza Sim, são as melhores práticas em ASP.NET MVC e EF até então.